# IIS URL Rewrite is not working when redirecting to another server

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I need to redirect links to a different server using URL rewrite in IIS.  These are SRSS report links.  I have tried so many different configurations i have given up.

Old Link:

http://OldServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?(reportnamehere - need to copy this part across to new link)

http://NewServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?reportnamehere

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 3. ARR must be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple rule requirement.  Something like this will work.  Basically just redirects to a new server appending the entire URL

```
<rule name="Redirect to newServer" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="(.*)" />      
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://NewServer/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />  
</rule>
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all, and nothing is shown when you do a network trace in IE. It just hits the old server.  I think it must be because its SSRS.  I will have look at alternative methods.

Comment: You're right, IIS was no longer used for SSRS starting in SSRS 2008.   If you are planning to retire the OldServer, you could shut off SSRS and install IIS such that it then receives the traffic and redirects.